# 2D Jagged array size change in c#

Tags: c#, 3d, jagged-arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCzOh.png)I am planning to calculate 3d coordinate points using vector3d. To find segmented points for a circle I thought i need to use jagged array to find the points. Can we change the size of the jagged array after initialization. In that case how?

I tried like this Vector3D[VerticesOfProfile][VerticeOfTrajetory] myVertices = new Vector3D[n][m]

I don't want to pre initialize n and m before as they vary based on size of the circle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku9E8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku9E8.png)

Comment: If your goal is to create a list of points on the circumference of a circle I fail to see why you would need a jagged array, or what "verticesOfTrajectory" would mean. And you would presumably know the size of the circle, so you could just compute the number of points needed and create an array of appropriate size.

Comment: You can't resize arrays after you've created them. All roads lead to creating a new array and copying data. Some methods are quicker than others. Also `new Vector3D[n][m]` isn't valid, as you can only declare the length of the main array, and you have to instantiate its child arrays separately.

Comment: @JonasH My goal was to create list of points on the circumference of a circle when it is swept through another curve passing through the circle axis. In my case the trajectory means another arc whose vertices should again be stepped polygons. That way i thought my first array parameter [n] will be a step in the trajectory and [m] will be step in the circular circumference for that [n] for that [m] there will be three coordinate points like x,y and z

Comment: I reedited my question with two images

Comment: I advise you to use a List<T> since you can resize it and it has many methods that could come in handy.
 Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: If you want to sweep a circle along a path, the simplest option would be to use fixed steps, that should allow you to pre-compute the number of points needed. Or just use a list.

Comment: You should be using a two dimension List : new List<List<Vector3D>>

Answer (score 0):

The way I would write this function would be something like this pseudo-code

```
var sweepPoints = new List<Vector3D[]>();

// Use 32 segments along the path, this could be computed depending on curvature if needed.
for(var i = 0; i < 32; i++){
    var t = i / 32d; // compute a 't' value in range 0-1 along the path;

    // Assuming you have something like a bezier-representation of a path
    // You would need the position and direction along the path.
    var pos = path.GetPositionAtT(t);
    var direction = path.GetDirectionAtT(t);

    // Create a circle from a position, direction and radius
    var circle= new Circle3D(pos , direction , 3);
    
    // Create 16 points around the circumference, you could compute the number of points from the radius if needed
    var circlePoints = circle.Segment(16);

    sweepPoints.Add(transform.Transform(circlePoints));
}
```

This does not technically need any dynamic arrays (i.e. `List<T>`) but it may make the code a bit more readable.

Also note that doing such sweep using an arbitrary shape and path will likely involve a fair amount of 3D math, so a good library and some basic knowledge of linear algebra will be very helpful.

In the simpler case of generating points describing a cylinder, as in your image, you know that you need two 'rings' of points, so this scenario should be fairly easy to handle. Just create a 3D-circle for each end-face and generate segments for each of the circles.